# Inflate children views in custom view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a class `Cell` which extends `LinearLayout`. During the creation of a new cell through the constructor, I would like to add views to the layout by inflating an xml layout. The problem is that to my eyes I have two choices:

1. inflating a single xml file which contains all the views under another layout
   OR
2. inflating multiple xml file, each one containing a different view

since I don't want to add another layout as a child of the layout, and neither I want to inflate many views, what would be the best way of doing that?

Comment: choice `1` is better create single xml layout so you can update it later and you will be able to remove / add views inside it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You could either create the view programmatically like

```
TextView t = new TextView(context)
```

but if you apply a lot of styles this is a real hassle.

The other easiest but slowest option is what you mentioned: inlate each view - mind you if you have many views (like 20+) this can really slow you down since inflating is very expensive.

The third option if you know your maximum number of dyamic view is to have a view with all the subviews you need maximal and just set all the others to invisbile. This is also a hack but way faster than.

The last and best option would be to inherit from `ListView` and just use an `Adapter`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't like the 3rd option because my view is not supposed to be a ListView in any way, it would be too forced. I will simply inflate a single layout